# Finding min/max Values Using Second Derivative Of A Rational Function

Tags: calculus

In the case of rational function, when taking the first derivative we take the numerator and find for which point the function is equal to zero.

Now, for the second derivative, can we take the second derivative just of the numerator? it is not intuitive, as we need to take the second derivative of the whole function, but I did not find a counterexample

For example the function: $x+8+\frac{50}{2x-4}$

Comment: where is your function to be seen?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $$f'(x)=1-\frac{100}{(2x-4)^2}$$ and $$f''(x)=\frac{400}{(2x-4)^3}$$
you can not take only the numerator for the second derivative, since we have a variable in the denominator